# Background removal with U2Net is too strong

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I am successfully using [U2Net](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net) to remove the background of images using the terminal and I am also using the nice interface of [this](https://github.com/OPHoperHPO/image-background-remove-tool) repo to do the same thing just in an easier way and validate the similarity of the results. However, my issue is that the background removal is too strong for images like this:

[image]

Where I get the following result (i.e. packaging is also removed):

[image]

If I upload the image in [Foco clipping website](https://www.fococlipping.com) and I select `Type=='Graphic'` I get exactly the same results. That means that the website is using the same algorithm to remove the background for Graphic-type images. Nevertheless, if I select `Type=='Product'`, then the result is the following and is exactly what I want:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on what to do to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you should sharpen the image first  (use strong sharpen)

[image: Example]

```
/* I've removed the code because I am not sure if it has some portion copied from other open-sourced codes, I am using it in my apps but I can't remember if it is quoted from other source, so I've removed it, also it could be auto-completed using github copilot */
```

2. use U2Net to remove the background of the sharpened image

[image: Example]

3. use the result from step (2) as mask

[image: Example]

4. using the mask from step (3) extract wanted result from original picture

[image: Example]

note: this is very quick example, you could refine it more

Comment: Hi @Jabbar, thanks for your answer. What do you mean by strong sharpen? I have tried  enhancer.enhance(200) from PIL and still the same

Comment: hello @azal , did you enhance sharpness or something else? check out sharpness class https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/python/PIL/ImageEnhance.html#class-sharpness

Also, I prefer if you use UnsharpMask https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/python/PIL/ImageFilter.html#class-unsharpmask

Comment: @azal I've used photopea.com Unsharp Mask, but you can use PIL, I 've added the code to the answer

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'you could refine it more? How?

Comment: @azal trying to change the variables in sharpen function to suit most of images

Comment: Thanks again. Could you take a look here please? Maybe you can answer this question too and I will accept again your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236396/remove-unwanted-parts-of-mask-image

Comment: @azal I've already answered the new question