# Remove unwanted parts of mask image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm successfully calculating the mask of an image using U2NET as seen below:

[image]

However, as can be seen, the mask is **not** completely white inside and also some unwanted artifacts can be observed outside the mask, i.e. left part.

I am trying to fix both of the aforementioned issues using dilation and erosion operations but I think this is the wrong approach as it does not produce the expected result.

I'm doing something like the following but does not fix the issue:

```
from PIL import ImageFilter

dilation_img = image.filter(ImageFilter.MaxFilter(15))
erotion_img = dilation_img.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter(15))
```

Comment: I think you are close, but need a slight different order.  Try doing an "opening operation" (ie erotion followed by equal steps of dilation), followed by a "closing operation" (dilation followed by equal steps of erosion).  Play with the number of steps of each based on the noise you are trying to remove in the form of islands for the opening operation and based the radius (half min cut) of the holes you are trying to fill in the closing operation.

Comment: Based on your image, I think that the opening operations will only require 2-3 steps, and the closing operation will likely require x2 or x3 that much (due to the large void on the right of the image)

Comment: hmm started writing the above, but seems this can largely be sorted with a simple threshold operation

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically threshold the image using Otsu's algorithm. After that you can fill in any hole by drawing over them with OpenCV contours. I'm not sure what value range U2Net can return when masking, but you also might just be alright manually setting a small threshold value ~50.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("mask.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

# otsu thresholding
_, mask = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU);

# show
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);

# close everything inside
contour, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

# get the biggest contour # returns _, contours, _ if using OpenCV 3
biggest_area = -1;
biggest = None;
for con in contour:
    area = cv2.contourArea(con);
    if biggest_area < area:
        biggest_area = area;
        biggest = con;

# fill in the contour
cv2.drawContours(mask, [biggest], -1, 255, -1);

# show
cv2.imshow("Filled Mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ian Chu, thanks so much for your answer. Are the above operations possible to be done using PIL or other libraries besides opencv?

Comment: It looks like scikit also has otsu thresholding and its own findContours function. I'm not too familiar with scikit, but the basic idea should be pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think this can be solved with a well placed binary threshold (as stated in another answer), adding an addition level of basic morphology should make it more robust to significantly dirtier images.  (sorry it is in C++)

I used an arbitrary binary threshold to demonstrate the concept, but would suggest using a statistics based threshold (such as otsu method) if available.

To explain the code a little: threshold converts the grayscale image to binary.  Opening removes external noise (any little strips, pieces, or pixel noise) left by the threshold op.  Closing infills any internal holes.  "opening" and "closing" are just names for combinations of dilates and erodes in specific order to achieve a desired effect without changing the underlying objects size/shape.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //C:/Local Software/voyDICOM/resources/images/oXsnC.jpg
    std::string fileName = "C:/Local Software/voyDICOM/resources/images/oXsnC.jpg";
    Mat tempImage = imread(fileName, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat bwImg;
    //binary thresh (both of these work, otsu just gets a "smarter" threshold value rather than a hardcoded one)
    cv::threshold(tempImage, bwImg, 150, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    //cv::threshold(tempImage, bwImg, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);
    
    Mat openedImage;
    //opening
    cv::erode(bwImg, openedImage, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 3)), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
    cv::dilate(openedImage, openedImage, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 3)), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);

    Mat closedImg;
    //closing
    cv::dilate(openedImage, closedImg, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 3)),cv::Point(-1,-1),5);
    cv::erode(closedImg, closedImg, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 3)), cv::Point(-1, -1), 5);


    namedWindow("Original", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Original", tempImage);

    namedWindow("Thresh", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Thresh", bwImg);

    namedWindow("Opened", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Opened", openedImage);

    namedWindow("Closed", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Closed", closedImg);

    waitKey(0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use binary thresholding to make parts not white but close to white to be white.

Another solution is to use [morphological operators](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/morops.htm) in order to fill or remove any gaps (Note that morphological operators like erode/dilate may need multiple passes on the image in order to get desired result).

Both can be used.

To automaticaly/adaptively compute the required threshold, the procedure I can think of is similar to performing morphological operations with suitable large structure elements. That is, scan regions of the image and use majority vote of that region's pixels to color all pixels of the region.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm doing pretty much what you proposed but could you provide a code example on both of your proposed solutions in order to accept your answer? Also my boundaries are very sharp instead of smooth

Comment: Thresholding is as simple as scanning the image and setting pixels to black or white depending on some carefully chosen threshold (that you can experiment with). Moreover you already have the code to perform morphological operations. You can try multiple passes of them

Comment: So there is no way to dynamically identify thresholds?

Comment: See updated answer for an approach to that, whic is similar to doing morphological operations

Answer (score 0):

1. use min filter (e.g MinFilter(8)) =  `result 1`
2. then apply max filter on `result 1` with same values of previous min (e.g MaxFilter(8)) =  `result 2`

[image: result 2]

3. use `result 2` as Mask for the original mask in the following way:

...

```
//assumptions: white=255, black=0
threshold = 128;// you can change it to give more weight for white or black
for(... loop all the the pixels)
for(...)
{
if((OrginalMask[x,y] > threshold) && (result2[x,y] < threshold))
    finalResult[x,y] = result2[x,y];//to remove unwanted artifacts outside the mask
else if ((OrginalMask[x,y] < threshold) && (result2[x,y] > threshold))
    finalResult[x,y] = result2[x,y];//to make the mask completely white inside
else
    finalResult[x,y] = OrginalMask[x,y];
}
```

[image: Final Result]